# Will a company I worked for briefly appear on a background check if I don't include it?

Tags: india, notice-period, background-check

Let's assume I left company A on 5th January (after serving my notice period). I joined company B on 7th January, but I did not like the culture and no seats were assigned to me. They asked me to work from home until they have a seat for me. I decided to leave the company without giving proper notice since they would ask me to serve the complete notice period. I also don't have any assets of this company. I joined a new company C the next day i.e 8th January.

Now come next year, I am looking for a job change, and obviously I will not mention anything about company B on my resume since it was just one day.

- Will my new company D get to know about the company B when they do background verification?
- Should I mention about this company B to my future employer as I absconded/left the company without any notice?
- Will this one day create problems for my future employments?

Comment: Kindly consider adding a country flag. It will be important to get relevant answers to your question. Additionally, what joining formalities and paperwork have you done with the company B? Have they taken any action after you absconded?

Comment: Signing on offer of employment on the day I got onboarded. They terminated me stating absconded.

Comment: Just for future reference, it's possible there may be a probationary period where you are not required to service the notice period.

Comment: I'm going to add the [India] tag as that's where it appears you are from.

Comment: I know that I would not. What possible explanation can there be for such inconsiderate behaviour? Certainly, the company did not behave particularly well, but the OP should have cited that as reason for resignation. Given the short period that the OP had been there, I doubt that the company would have insisted on working the notice period, as there could be no possible benefit to the company.

Answer (score 5):

My instinct is to say it shouldn't matter, but...
I would have to say it's dependent on turnover and resources invested in new employees/candidates by the hiring company.

If you're talking about low paying, high turnover jobs such as food services,
delivery and so on, companies tend to spend less resources on new employees, as the employer can (reasonably) expect high rates turnover, absconding etc.

It might relevant if the new company is in any way affiliated with the old, absconded one, but it usually only happens in small or niche markets.
Additionally, if the hiring process is a highly invested one, then the hiring company might actually research your employment history, but usually it's expressed as a request for recommendations from previous employers.

#### TL;DR

I wouldn't be too worried about, but it's not a good practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already considering a move from C in a year or less then even that is going to raise eyebrows. You will *probably* not be called out on your day at B, but people do talk amongst their network, and if anyone joins the dots you will get a bad reputation as a job-hopper.

You would do well to understand *why* you're already looking for job D - are you not doing due diligence about the company culture when recruited? Could you *really* have a fair view of B in just one day, or are you overreacting to minor points? What's bad about C and are you serious about moving to D? The perfect employer doesn't exist and you need to know yourself and just what you need to be content.